# Android sqlite query for string

Tags: android, sqlite

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname FROM people WHERE lastname='John Kenedy'; ",null);
```

Is that correct usage of comparing `String` ? if no, How can I compare `String` values in the database?

Comment: you can use "=" for straight string comparisons, there's also `LIKE`, `GLOB`, `REGEXP` and `MATCH` (if you are using a free-text search table/fts3) - what is your **use case**? Oh, and btw, performance is improved by [SQLiteStatements](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) - *not* tweaking `rawQuery` with parameters - that just prevents injections.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For better performance, you should use `rawQuery` method with `selectionArgs` which is faster and more secure against adding directly data to statement. So try it like this

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id,lastname FROM people WHERE lastname = ?; ", new String[] {"John Kenedy"});
```